# How can I catch all tooltips from my application & display it in Status bar in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

My task is simple.
I want to catch any tooltip is show throughout a WinForms C# Application and then display it, as well, in the Status Bar.

how to achieve such functionality?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by any hint? you mean like exceptions?

Comment: I think OP means tooltips

Comment: You could use the `ToolTip.Popup` event.

Comment: No no no...
the tool tip itself is showing, but I need to catch the text and show it in the status bar IN addition

Comment: @OussamaAlRifai, that was @Luaan's point.  You can register an event handler for your `ToolTip`'s `Popup` event so that every time it pops up, you can read the `Text` property and update the status bar.  Of course, this gets ugly if you use several `ToolTip` objects in your application, but if you only have one, it's a good solution.

Comment: That's a pretty strange UI requirement. What if some tooltips are owner drawned? How would you want to deal with those?

Comment: @corno. It is just a requirement. But why you see it strange. It is almost a standard. Have a look to office application. You will see it there. And not only in office applications.

Comment: @OussamaAlRifai Open Excel and put mouse over any toolbar button. A tooltip appear but there's no status bar changes. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are right. I am pretty sure it was there in previous versions.  Anyway, No harm done. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick example of using the `Popup()` event as mentioned in the comments.  Note I'm using `e.AssociatedControl` to get a reference to the control that is the source of the event, and `GetToolTip()` to retrieve the tip from it:

```
    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl);
    }
```

Comment: OP didn't mention it but I'm guessing he'd want the label cleared when the tooltip disappears as well.